# chapterfolder or import for a thesis with figures in subdirectories

Tags: graphics, import, folders

I've been poking around on here trying to work out the best way of keeping my individual chapters and their associated figures in subdirectories. After reading a few threads I've been testing out `chapterfolder` and `import` (example at the bottom). Is there any particular advantage to using one or the other? Both seem extremely similar. Thus far the only differences seem to be:

- The need for a workaround for `\includegraphics` with `chapterfolder`
- `chapterfolder` automatically inserts the chapter title, whereas I'd need to do that manually with `import`.

Given that the latter might actually be an advantage (e.g. if I wanted to process the chapter individually without the parent document), I'm currently leaning towards `import`. Is there anything I'm missing?

Exmple below: what I'd really like to do is not have to add the subdirectory `figures` to each of my 
`\includegraphics{figures/fig1.pdf}` commands - I have a lot of figures to do this for manually, but I am pretty sure there is no way to define a `\graphicspath` for each subdirectory individually - am I right?

Example:

parent directory contains:
`main.tex`
`subfolder/sub.tex`
`subfolder/figures/fig1.pdf`

where `subfolder/sub.tex` consists of:

```
text

\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics{figures/fig1.pdf}
  \caption{caption}
\end{figure}
```

and `main.tex` consists of:

**Option 1**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{graphicx}    % needed for including graphics
\usepackage{import}

\begin{document}

\subimport{introduction/}{introduction.tex}

\end{document}
```

**or Option 2**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{graphicx}    % needed for including graphics
\usepackage{chapterfolder}
% and we re-write includegraphics
\let\includegraphicsWithoutCF\includegraphics
\renewcommand{\includegraphics}[2][]{\includegraphicsWithoutCF[#1]{\cfcurrentfolder#2}}

\begin{document}

\cfchapter{Introduction}{introduction}{introduction.tex}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I guess nobody has any opinions on this. I'm sticking with import for now. And going through all my documents typing "figures/" a lot of times...

Comment: Did you find a better solution for this ? I am also having the same problem. Would be great help to know. Thanks.

Comment: @Anusha As I said in that comment on Feb 10, I stuck with `\subimport` since nobody pointed out any obvious downsides. If you are just starting up, it's not so much of a big deal to add a subdirectory pointing to the graphics location in each `\includegraphics` statement. It was a bit annoying for me as I already had quite a lot of work in standalone files I was wanting to incorporate, but it didn't take too long to convert. Sorry for the delay in replying, I was on holiday!

Answer (score 1):

I have been trying to get the same thing done, and here is what has worked for me (if you haven't already figured something out). My situation is similar in that I have a main thesis folder, and then chapter sub folders with additional figure subfolders. The structure is something like:

- Main Dir

  - mainthesis.tex
  - Chapter1 Dir

    - Chapter1.tex
    - Figures

      - YouCanDoIt.pdf

With as many chapter folders as needed. I'm using the import package (like you are I believe).
A simplified version of mainthesis.tex is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}  %12pt is larger than 11pt

\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}

% save the meaning of \includegraphics
\LetLtxMacro\latexincludegraphics\includegraphics

% redefine \includegraphics to refer to the subfolder Figures
\renewcommand{\includegraphics}[2][ ]{\latexincludegraphics[#1]{Figures/#2}}

%========= Main Document ============
\begin{document}

\subincludefrom{Chapter1/}{Chapter1}

\end{document}
```

Where Chapter1.tex looks something like

```
\section{Introduction}

\subsection{This is the first subsection}
\begin{figure} 
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{YouCanDoIt}
\caption{Motivational Graphic.}
\end{figure}
```

As far as I can tell, the only limitation with this approach is that all figures in the entire document need to be located in a "Figures" subdirectory to the current working directory. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @brewsclues: it is precisely that limitation that I can't work with! I have a lot of figures and it does my head in having them all in one directory. So I have stuck with my Option 1 above: I've now gone through and added the subdirectory path to all my `\includegraphics` calls anyway, so no point switching method now!